# Join on Update Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-update, left-join

I have two tables: One is InvWarehouse which contains most of the data. The other is InvMaster+ which contains what I'm filtering on (Which is SalesDemandClass).

How do I join these in an update statement?

Here's what I have so far, but it doesn't work. I tried to connect them on StockCode (which is in both), but if I put InvWarehouse A it says it expects the SET to be there instead.

```
    update InvWarehouse A
set MinimumQty = SafetyStockQty, MaximumQty = (SafetyStockQty * 3)
from InvWarehouse
left join [InvMaster+] B on A.StockCode = B.StockCode
where SalesDemandClass in ('D4','D8','D12')
```

Comment: What is your DBMS product

Comment: The answer heavily depends on the specific database. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Making the assumption from the square bracket delimiters this is SQL Server, you need the correct syntax:

```
 update iw set 
   iw.MinimumQty = im.SafetyStockQty, 
   iw.MaximumQty = SafetyStockQty * 3
from InvWarehouse iw
left join [InvMaster+] im on im.StockCode = iw.StockCode
where iw.SalesDemandClass in ('D4','D8','D12');
```

Try to get in the [good habit](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3) of using meaningful table aliases and *using* them for all columns to avoid you and others guessing.